# scraping table data based on date

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

iam trying to scrape table of kurs transaction https://www.bi.go.id/id/moneter/informasi-kurs/transaksi-bi/Default.aspx

from 2015-2020, but the problem is the link between the default date and the date that I chose is still the same. So how can I tell python to scrape data from 2015-2020(20-Nov-15 -- 20-nov-20)? I'm very new to python and  using python 3.thank you in advance

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
headers={
"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.101 Safari/537.36",
"X-Requested-With":"XMLHttpRequest"
}
url = "https://www.bi.go.id/id/moneter/informasi-kurs/transaksi-bi/Default.aspx"
import requests
from lxml import html
response = requests.get(url)
content= response.content
print(content)
```

Comment: `the link between the default date and the date that I chose is still the same` - what adinda means is that the url does not change to reflect the date range queried, which means that `bs4` cannot be used to directly access the desired page.

Answer (score 1):

A few different approaches:

- Use array slicing if you are working with 1 dimensional data
- Use filter / groupby methods from the Pandas library after putting your data into a dataframe

Answer (score 1):

The website requires you to enter in start and end dates for the query. However, as far as I know, `bs4` only scrapes html that is already displayed on the browser, and is not so useful for making a query on the web site itself.

From the source code and the POST request it looks like a complicated request so you might be better off simulating mouse clicks.

This can be done using the automated browser testing `selenium` package to automate opening Google Chrome browser, entering the date into the From and To fields, then clicking the Lihat button, waiting for page to load, then scraping the displayed table using `bs4` or `selenium`.